# Drawing multiple HTML canvases only draws the last one?

Tags: javascript, html, loops, canvas, for-loop

In an application I'm writing there is a page where I load multiple base64-encoded images from my database and place them inside a JavaScript array. This is happening on the server via EJS templating, so when the user receives the HTML page the base64-encoded images are present (I checked this).

Next step is using JavaScript on the client-side to loop over the canvases and then fill each canvas with its corresponding image data. However, I'm getting some strange behaviour. Only the last canvas is filled each time.

```
for (var i = 1; i < 13; i++) {
    var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas-' + i).getContext('2d'),
        image = new Image();

    image.onload = function() {
        ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
    }
    image.src = images[(i - 1)];
}
```

The images array is defined right above this code (in the same scope). If I execute the code like this only the last canvas (with the id 'canvas-12') will be filled. If I lower the for loop end condition to for example i < 11, only canvas with id 'canvas-10' will be filled.

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Seems like a closure issue; each time you go through to loop, you are changing the object `ctx` included in the `onload` function. You need to make sure that you aren't updating the objects during the loop by using a closure:

```
for (var i = 1; i < 13; i++) {
    var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas-' + i).getContext('2d'),
        image = new Image();
    (function(ctx, image) {
        image.onload = function() {
            ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
        }
        image.src = images[(i - 1)];
    })(ctx, image);
}
```

NOTE: I have not tested this.

Comment: @SimonSarris there is probably a suitable _exact duplicate_ for this question somewhere. It's a common problem.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick! I'll accept your answer after the 5 minute  limit :)